# Why do my display settings revert after I reboot?

Tags: gnome, display, dualhead, gnome-control-center

Specifically, I have to set which of my two monitors is on the right every time I reboot. I'm using gnome-control-center, in Gnome3. Ubuntu 14.04.

Why are my settings being reverted when I reboot?